# Are French postmodernism, Critical Theory and their heirs related to idealism?

Tags: idealism, postmodernism, critical-theory

Are French postmodernism (Foucault, Derrida, Deleuze, etc.), and Critical Theory (Adorno, Marcuse, etc.), and their heirs such as gender and postcolonial studies (Butler, Saïd) related to idealism?

Are they idealist theories?

Because their theory is basically that any sociological phenomenon is boiled down to social/cultural construction, in other words that everything is about ideas.

Comment: Yes and no... Adorno, Marcuse are marxists; thus they obviously would not agree being called "idealists". But in a sense Marxism is a "transformation" of Hegel philosophy...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Don't really understand how Marxism which is a materialism could be influenced as it was by an idealist theory, which is hegelianism. I know it is still the case, but...

Comment: [Dialectical materialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectical_materialism) "is a philosophy developed in Europe and based on the writings of Karl Marx and Friedrich Engels. In keeping with dialectical ideas [i.e.  Hegelian philosophy,], Marx and Engels thus created an alternative theory..."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, then marxism retained the dialectic part of the hegelian theory, not the idealistic part

Comment: Agreeing with Mauro's comments, critical theory, is to a large extend, opposed to post-modernism. Intersection points and some agreements do exist, nevertheless on various issues.

Comment: why were my comments deleted @MauroALLEGRANZA do you mean to say that there is no link between idealism and nominalism, anti-essentialism and anti-realism? all are opposed to realism, i think, which materialism is an articulation of "Materialism is an ontological thesis that posits that being can be independent of thinking, while realism posits the thinkability of this being independent of thinking"

Comment: adrono died of a heart attack in 1969 @NikosM. how could he be opposed to post modernism?

Comment: "say that there is no link between idealism and nominalism, anti-essentialism and anti-realism?" I'm not saying that... I'm not involved in the struggle between "-isms". What I'm saying is that most of the philosophers quoted above are "marxists-like" that mean that in principle they are inclined to materialism.

Comment: ok sorry to bother anyone. i don't know much @MauroALLEGRANZA about the topic HTH

Comment: @Starckman there are continuators of critical theory

Comment: @anonymous Do you imply that materialism is a continuation of realism, in the same way that idealism is a continuation of anti-realism?

Comment: There is nothing American with Frankfurt School thinkers. Adorno, Horckheimer, Marcuse, Benjamin...they literally had been members of an sociological institute based in Frankfurt (Main), Germany, and every one of them was German.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Edited. Many emigrated to the US, so I wrongly associate it to the US, where it is still quite powerful now (in comparison to France and Germany). Thanks!

Comment: French postmodernists and, as far as i understand it, critical theory have historical-materialist bases. In those works social and cultural constructions are ideas, but ideas held by people and determined by their material conditions of existences. For exemple, "race" is an idea, but not an idea that floats outside of a material context like a platonician Form. According to CT the idea of race was developped to justify the domination of European powers over colonized people, i.e. "it's ok to brutalize those people and take their lands because they are inferior"

Comment: @armand What you describe makes me think of Marx. It is the common ground (marxism and postmodernism/CT) of Hegel?

Comment: Historical materialism was coined by Marx, but one can have a materialist analysis of history and not still not be marxist. Marx developped his own theory of history in  opposition to Hegel, who thought the dialog(-> dialectic) of ideas drove history and great leaders were embodiment of the spirit of their time, where Marx who denied ideas existed out of people's mind replied it's actually people's material conditions that determine their ideas (-> dialectical materialism). He took part of Hegels system and changed what seemed fishy in his views, which is still an influence.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I'd say there is a clear NO.

I'd like to differentiate between the -isms and technical terms and the gist and goal here, though.

#### Regarding the authors as idealists

As far as I am aware, both the French postmodernists  and Critical Theory are explicit about material conditions forming thought, not the other way around. And yes, cultural upbringing is a *material* condition that produces materially dependent ideas. They are not and never "just ideas".

What they also have in common are two things:

1. The goal/aspiration/reminder to lay bare what those material conditions (education, socioeconomic status, power, culture, language, you name it) are and how they influence the thinking
2. That for rational decision making, this is only the first step and we need to deliberate ourselves from those conditions in a second step.

The main differences between individual philosophies are

1. What they think the main material driver is
2. Inhowfar they say we can only be descriptive about or see *past* material conditions since we cannot separate our thinking and being from our current conditions (like Foucault's *episteme*)
3. Inhowfar we can overcome and actively *change* current conditions

None of them would ascribe to idealism and it would be an unfair oversimplification of all the authors named if we called them idealists IMHO.

#### Regarding similarities/alliances

We could say that those philosophies and idealism kind of have the same *pragmatic goal*: They want to make place for a deliberation from determinism.

While they describe and acknowledge material conditions and being, they (most of them, if not all of them at some point) try to make it possible for the individual and social thinking to be able to overcome and change those conditions.

Therefore, in a sense, they pursue a goal that they have in common with most modern (ie. Post-medieval) idealist philosophies.

Comment: Postmodernism and Critical Theory have given birth to the gender studies, which basically deny any influence of the biological/material; and again, all is about "construction" and "language", so... I know I repeat myself but...

Comment: @Starckman Firstly, I expanded a bit. Secondly, gender studies do not deny the biological, they just say that gender is not genetically determined and a social construct different from sex, and as such part of structures of language, power, etc. that need to be critically examined and can be subject to change. It is an empirical fact that social roles are heavily influenced not only by sex but also by cultural influences. Therefore, I smell a strawman here.

Comment: "It is an empirical fact that social roles are heavily influenced not only by sex but also by cultural influences." Not sure that the gender studies limit themselves to saying that social roles are "heavily influenced by cultural influences"

Comment: @Starckman I am sure there are extremist forms. Lumping them all together won't help any serious discussion, though. You always need to judge individual positions separately, like with -isms, or you will necessarily be unfair to all but one.

Comment: *"gender studies, which basically deny any influence of the biological/material"*  It seems you haven't done any reading on the topic. Perhaps you might start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_construction_of_gender#Applications_of_gender_performance

Comment: "We act as if that being of a man or that being of a woman is actually an internal reality or something that's simply true about us, a fact about us. Actually, it's a phenomenon that is being produced all the time and reproduced all the time, so to say gender is performative is to say that nobody really is a gender from the start." Butler, from the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Starckman Yeah but well it actually says that it is "being reproduced all the time", it is perptually and performatively (re-)enforced by the person and their surroundings. How is that saying it was "just an idea" and not materially formed and conditioned?

Comment: "We act and walk and speak and talk in ways that consolidate an **impression** of being a man or being a woman..." Butler, from the Wikipedia article

Comment: "there is no 'being' behind doing... 'the doer' is merely a fiction added to the deed – the deed is everything" Butler, from the Wikipedia article

Comment: @Starckman That's a form of *pragmatism*, and pragmatism usually does not fit well with either materialism or idealism. They tend to have some fashion of process ontology or no ontological commitment at all. And Butler says that the fiction is the primacy of the person/mind behind the action over the action itself, ie. this is pretty much arguing *against idealism*.

Comment: @Starckman at no point in your quotes does it "basically deny any influence of the biological/material". Note that in her lexicon "man" and "woman" are social roles, and not equivalent to "male" and "female". i.e. the way we ought to perform to meet social norms and expectations is for a large part not based on the type of gametes we emit (for those who can emit them). And the type of gametes we emit can't be changed just by thinking about it.

Comment: "And Butler says that the fiction is the primacy of the person/mind behind the action over the action itself" To what I understood, she says that the "being" (which refers to the biological material) does not exist. Only the action exists. The action creates an impression, which is the doer (a social role of "man" or "woman"), which is simply a fiction.

Comment: The action is seen as a social role, as a set of codes/symbols that gives "impression", in other words, they are "ideas". Only that exists. The being (the biological), does not exist.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, pragmatism was strongly influenced by German idealism